# Is ECDiffieHellmanCng safe?

Tags: c#, security, networking, encryption

I want to use this class to establish a secure connection from my client to my server. I have not worked with encryption or networking at all previously to this, and I have a couple of questions about this class and its safety based on some research I did.

- I understand diffie hellman can by broken trough a man in middle attack and a way to protect yourself would be for the server to create a hash of the message and encrypt it with its private key, then the client decrypts it with the server's public key and sees if the hash is valid. Does this class do this automatically or do I need to do that myself?
- I also understand that for roughly 10 years a backdoored pseudorandom number generator using an eliptic curve (which I believe this class uses) named Dual_EC_DRBG was the standard for encryption. The claim that it is secure was withdrawn roughly 5 years ago, but I am wondering if this or any other possibly unsecure functions are used in the class, in which case I may be able to use other secure ones?
- I looked a bit into "Zeroisation". The keys are stored in the RAM, of course. Does the garbage collector take care of those as soon as the app is closed or should I do something such as zeroing/overwriting them myself?

Comment: Is TLS already dead?

Comment: I would rather make my own thing that achieves that rather than using a wrapper that does everything for me

Comment: Yeah, instead of trusting the tech you use for virtually anything secure in the web, like shopping, banking, or any login out there. let's create our own thing, with privative code that no one will review apart from our team. Also your own thing will be maintained and extensively tested as the time goes by right? You can do your own application but for Transport Security, there's a good solution that gets you covered. Please use that, do it for your users. And btw if you're thinking about your own way of storing passwords... that's also a bad idea.

Comment: Well I am planning to use the tested cryptography classes from C#, I just want to make sure everything is covered. I need to have more control over what is going on because of how my server works (it is not a website, by the way). Also, I am not storing passwords, but when, for example, the shared password gets sent to the client and he stores it in a byte array, for example, I do not want it to stay there past the part where the program exits, thats what i meant

Comment: Yes, diffie-hellman is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle without authentication, but authentication is more complicated than you make it out to be. Simply signing your keys with another unauthenticated key doesn't really help. ECDiffieHellmanCng has *nothing* to do with Dual_EC_DRBG, which is a randomizer that I'm sure is long gone from Windows. Are you using a very old, unpatched version of Windows? Good question about zeroization, but somebody with a stronger stomach than I will have to scour Microsoft's documentation for the answer.

Comment: Previous broken versions of SSL / TLS are also implemented using generic algorithms present in the .NET framework. Actually, the more secure ciphers are missing from it.